# Can someone tell why my android app is force closing when loading images into gallery

Tags: android, android-gallery

I'm loading images from my phone gallery and loading it into my app gallery, but each time I run the app it force closes.

My code:

```
 public class ImageActivity extends Activity {


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.imagelayout);

    Gallery gallery = (Gallery) findViewById(R.id.gallery);
    gallery.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));


    gallery.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() 
    {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, 
        View v, int position, long id) 
        {                
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), 
                    "pic" + (position + 1) + " selected", 
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```

}

```
 public class ImageLoader {

    private List<String> ImageFiles = new ArrayList<String>();
    private static final String CAMERA_IMAGE_BUCKET_NAME = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+ "/DCIM/Camera";    
    private File file;

    public ImageLoader(){
        ReadImages();
    }

    public List<String> getImageFiles(){
        return ImageFiles;
    }

    private void ReadImages(){
        file = new File(CAMERA_IMAGE_BUCKET_NAME);
        File[] URIs = file.listFiles(new ImageFileFilter());
        for(int x = 0; x < URIs.length; x++){
            File file = URIs[x];
            ImageFiles.add(file.getPath());
        }
    }

    /**
     * Image File Filter Class
     */
    public class ImageFileFilter implements FileFilter{

        private final String[] AndroidExtensions = new String[] {"jpg", "png"};

        public boolean accept(File pathname) {
            for (String extension : AndroidExtensions)
            {
              if (pathname.getName().toLowerCase().endsWith(extension))
              {
                return true;
              }
            }
            return false;
        }

    }

}

public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

     private Context context;
     private int itemBackground;
     List<String> images;
     ImageLoader loader; 


     public ImageAdapter(Context c){
         loader = new ImageLoader();
         images = loader.getImageFiles();
         context = c;
         //---setting the style---
         TypedArray a = c.obtainStyledAttributes(R.styleable.gallery);
         itemBackground = a.getResourceId(
             R.styleable.gallery_android_galleryItemBackground, 0);
         a.recycle();  
     }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return images.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }


    //---returns an ImageView view---
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);
        try{
            Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(images.get(position).toString());  

            imageView.setImageBitmap(bm); 
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            Log.e("DEBUGTAG", "Remtoe Image Exception", e);
        }

        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(150, 100));
        imageView.setBackgroundResource(itemBackground);
        return imageView;
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help!

```
Stack trace:
Thread [<1> main] (Suspended (exception OutOfMemoryError))  
    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(String, BitmapFactory$Options) line: 277   
    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(String) line: 296  
    ImageAdapter.getView(int, View, ViewGroup) line: 63 
    Gallery.makeAndAddView(int, int, int, boolean) line: 745    
    Gallery.fillToGalleryRight() line: 697  
    Gallery.layout(int, boolean) line: 628  
    Gallery.onLayout(boolean, int, int, int, int) line: 336 
    Gallery(View).layout(int, int, int, int) line: 7035 
    LinearLayout.setChildFrame(View, int, int, int, int) line: 1249 
    LinearLayout.layoutVertical() line: 1125    
    LinearLayout.onLayout(boolean, int, int, int, int) line: 1042   
    LinearLayout(View).layout(int, int, int, int) line: 7035    
    LinearLayout.setChildFrame(View, int, int, int, int) line: 1249 
    LinearLayout.layoutHorizontal() line: 1238  
    LinearLayout.onLayout(boolean, int, int, int, int) line: 1044   
    LinearLayout(View).layout(int, int, int, int) line: 7035    
    FrameLayout.onLayout(boolean, int, int, int, int) line: 333 
    FrameLayout(View).layout(int, int, int, int) line: 7035 
    PhoneWindow$DecorView(FrameLayout).onLayout(boolean, int, int, int, int) line: 333  
    PhoneWindow$DecorView(View).layout(int, int, int, int) line: 7035   
    ViewRoot.performTraversals() line: 1045 
    ViewRoot.handleMessage(Message) line: 1727  
    ViewRoot(Handler).dispatchMessage(Message) line: 99 
    Looper.loop() line: 123 
    ActivityThread.main(String[]) line: 4627    
    Method.invokeNative(Object, Object[], Class, Class[], Class, int, boolean) line: not available [native method]  
    Method.invoke(Object, Object...) line: 521  
    ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() line: 858  
    ZygoteInit.main(String[]) line: 616 
    NativeStart.main(String[]) line: not available [native method]
```

Comment: Can we see the stack trace please?

Comment: Where do I get the stack trace in eclipse?

Comment: OKay I have added the stack trace

Comment: I noticed you have an Activity Class missing in the code above, how are you running this app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed the getView method to this:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);
    try{
        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inTempStorage = new byte[16*1024];
        Bitmap bm = this.decodeFile(images.get(position).toString());  

        imageView.setImageBitmap(bm); 
        //bm.recycle();
        bm = null;
        System.gc();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        Log.e("DEBUGTAG", "Remtoe Image Exception", e);
    }

    imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
    imageView.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(150, 100));
    imageView.setBackgroundResource(itemBackground);
    return imageView;
}
```

And I Used a new decode method I got from [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477572/android-strange-out-of-memory-issue/823966#823966)

```
private Bitmap decodeFile(String f){
    try {
        //Decode image size
        BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f),null,o);

        //The new size we want to scale to
        final int REQUIRED_SIZE=70;

        //Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
        int width_tmp=o.outWidth, height_tmp=o.outHeight;
        int scale=1;
        while(true){
            if(width_tmp/2<REQUIRED_SIZE || height_tmp/2<REQUIRED_SIZE)
                break;
            width_tmp/=2;
            height_tmp/=2;
            scale*=2;
        }

        //Decode with inSampleSize
        BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o2.inSampleSize=scale;
        return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o2);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {}
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

An OutOfMemoryError is usually because you are trying to decode a compressed image but in doing so you fill up the heap. Gallery images on smartphones phones can be huge (several MB in size) once decompressed. You need to work with the compressed version of the file or only work with pieces of the picture at a time.

Comment: I don't know exactly what you want to do but if it's just showing the picture, then Android's native widgets can work with Gallery images directly.